# Error on dotnet restore command

Tags: .net

I have a project targeted to dotnet core 1.1.1 and when trying to restore package on Mac give me the error:

> /Users/abdul.badru/2017/Projects/MPDC/OTC2/otc-api/OTCApi/src/OTCApi/OTCApi.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Microsoft/Visu
>   alStudio/v14.0/DotNet/Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

On windows the project restore and run successfully.

What could be the problem knowing that I have created the project using Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Microsoft moved from project.json to .csproj file. I had to migrate the project using the command: **dotnet migrate**

More info on [Announcing .NET Core Tools MSBuild “alpha”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.10. Then found the following post
https://github.com/Kwoth/NadekoBot/issues/1132

> Force install outdated 1.0.0-preview2 dotnet version.

And that did the trick!